# How can I combine two arrays into one array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

with `console.info(hora);` I print the array:

```
 ["NO HORA", 1, "NO HORA", 1]
```

and with `console.info(self.aEstados.estados);` I print the array:

```
 ["SI CONTIENE", "NO CONTIENE", 2]
```

But I need the arrays together:

```
 ["NO HORA", 1, "NO HORA", 1, "SI CONTIENE", "NO CONTIENE", 2]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

use `Array.prototype.concat` method:

```
var result = hora.concat(self.aEstados.estados);
```

Comment: i have this error Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Comment: it's because `hora` is `undefined`, make sure you have the right data inside `hora`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.concat` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat )

```
var combined = hora.concat( self.aEstados.estados );
console.info( combined );
```

Comment: Hi , i have this error : Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Comment: @Jeanbf you need to call `concat` in a function that has both `hora` and `self.aEstados.estados` in-scope.